# Not Getting Facebook Profile Image,Inpale of that getting question marks or dots unity

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine

I am try to get Facebook profile images (at least 10 friends profile images), but I am not able to retrieve them. In place of profile images I am getting question mark sign or dots, I don't know why this is happening. My code is as follows:

```
FB.API (Util.GetPictureURL(game.GetScoreList()[i].GetFacebookProfile().GetId(), 128,128), Facebook.HttpMethod.GET, delegate(FBResult pictureResult){

    // if there was an error
    if(pictureResult.Error != null)  {
        Debug.Log (pictureResult.Error);
    }
    // if everything was fine
    else {
        fbpic.sprite = Sprite.Create (pictureResult.Texture, new Rect(0,0,500,500), new Vector2(0,0));
    }
});
```

Comment: can you report a bug at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/? We can debug using your access token there.